# How to share a filehandle between threads in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, http

I have two threads,

One runs a loop with HTTP::Daemon, and the other runs a IO::Select based socket server.

Now when user connects to the HTTP service it will need to write to the client of the socket server.

However, in Perl I cannot share a filehandle with `threads::shared`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Need a bit more detail on what you're doing. You may find you can pass the filehandle via a `Thread::Queue` which I much prefer over `threads::shared`.

Answer (score 2):

File *descriptors* are global to the process and you can dereference a filehandle to its descriptor using `fileno`. Then it's just a matter of passing that simple scalar value between threads and reopening by number.

In your `HTTP::Daemon` thread:

```
my $fileno = fileno $fh;
```

The pass the number to the `IO::Select` thread by whatever means your program is using (e.g. a shared array). And reopen the handle by number in the `IO::Select` thread:

```
open my $fh, "&=$fileno";
```